# MongoDB query array containing search text

Tags: mongodb, mongomapper

I have the following query (MongoMapper/Rails):
    Card.where(:card_tags => {:$all => search_tags}

Where card_tags is an array of string tags and search_tags is in array of the search strings. At the moment if someone searches 'snow', no results with tag 'snowboarding' will be returned.

How can I modify this query to search whether any strings in card_tags contains any of the strings in search_tags? Regular expressions come to mind but not sure of the syntax given these are arrays...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions but you will be doing full collection scans - this is going to be bad for performance.

You can use regex with an index only if you "starts with" type of searches, but I doubt you want to limit yourself to that.

For fulltext searching, you are better off using some external search service for this - like Lucene, ElasticSearch, or Solr.

Refer to this post too: [like query in mongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340045/like-query-in-mongodb/5340159#5340159)

Comment: Thanks! I know the regex syntax from the link you sent, but any idea how I can incoporate this into my query which is comparing two arrays of strings? I basically need some way of wrapping the regex around each of the search_tags elements.